# html5 selection issue in ios6 - works in ios5

Tags: javascript, ios, html

We have a webpage that allows the user to click on a button to save the highlighted text. This occurs in a frame. The code we have works when run on ios v5, but against ios 6 it does not work. The selection appears to be removed before the touchstart function executes.

Please go to http://athena.atomus.com/bluec/selectionTestFrame.html.

1. Long press some text and highlight it
2. click the button
3. under ios5 you will see an alert with your highlighted text. Under
   ios6 you will see an alert with undefined

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Ok so some progress. On ios safari, the div containing the selected text receives the mouseout event, just before the click event is sent to the button. I think that in this event I would be able to capture the selection. However as soon as I add a mouseout handler, the ios selection function stops working, e.g. you can't select the text. I do not call preventDefault on the event. So my plan is to handle the event and save the selection in memory, then in the onclick handler do what I want to do. How can I do this?